# WiFi not working on HP 430 Probook with Intel 8260 WiFi hardware

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel-wireless, firmware, wifi-hardware-switch

I tried installing, Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP Probook and WiFi is not working.

I tried updating my firmware to 1.127.15, still it does not work. The laptop has Intel 8260 WiFi Hardware.

Is there anything I can do to fix my WiFi?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

14.04 is too old for this very new device. To upgrade your WiFi drivers without upgrading all your system, you can try installing Core13 from:

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release

Comment: I had upgraded my kernel to 4.0.5, then upgraded. Nothing had happened. I followed the instructions in the link you mentioned, the backporting stuff - rebooted, and wifi's working. Thanks a tonne!

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your Kernel to 4.x if it is currently on 3.19 or older, that worked for me

check kernel version with:

`uname -a`

Answer (score -1):

These issue will normally get fixed by upgrading the firware

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

If the same issue reoccurs after following the above steps please do follow the command below and check for error to further proceed on this issue

> lspci -nnk | grep -EA3 Ralink

Comment: -1 What? The `b43` stands for a series of Broadcom wireless adapters. This one here is made by Intel.